# Fragment setTitle and set Menu

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to set activity tilte and menu from fragment, 
(Below code is working well, but i looking for a better implementation)

in 1st step, i created a `interface`

```
public interface IGetDetails {
    public String getTitle();
    public int getMenu();
}
```

every fragment implements this Interface

for example

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements IGetDetails {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tes, null);
    }


    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return "test Title";
    }

    @Override
    public int getMenu() {
        return R.menu.test;
    }
}
```

**In Activity**
I used a stack to record frgments

```
Stack<Fragment> fragmentStack=new Stack<>();
```

when user navigate from one fragment to another,i added new fragment to stack.example

```
            currentFragment=new TestFragment();
            fragmentStack.push(currentFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.bodyFragment, currentFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            setTitle();
```

in `onBackpressed`

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0){
            FragmentManager manager =getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction trans = manager.beginTransaction();
            trans.remove( fragmentStack.pop());
            trans.commit();
            manager.popBackStack();
            currentFragment=fragmentStack.lastElement();
             setTitle();
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

`setTitle` Method in Activity

```
public void setTitle() {

        IGetDetails fragment = (IGetDetails) currentFragment;
        if (fragment != null) {
            String title = fragment.getTitle();
            if (title == null || title.equals("")) {
                setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            } else {
                setTitle(title);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just override onAttach and onDetach() in your Fragment Class.

for ex-

```
    @Override
public void onDetach() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDetach();
    getActionBar().setTitle("My Account");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Menus your Fragment has to call
 setHasOptionsMenu(true)
in it's onCreate method.

Then just override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onOptionsItemSelected` to populate your menu and listen for clicks.

To set the title from the fragment use `getActivity().setTitle()`, for example in the `onActivityCreated` method :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("My Fragment Title");
}
```

Note: this does only work for API>=11

Answer (score 0):

For titles, you need to set the title in `onStart()`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).setTitle();
    }
}
```

Since `onStart()` is called every time the fragment will be loaded, you will always be displaying the title of the currently displayed fragment.

To load options menu of your Fragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //if using fragments from support library
        ((FragmentActivity)getActivity()).setTitle();
        //otherwise
        getActivity().setTitle();
    }
}
```

Now override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and load the menu you want to display there. There's no need for a workaround when Android provides you with a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. For setting title of Current fragment.

   ```
       currentFragment=new TestFragment();
       ...
       setTitle(currentFragment.getTitle());
   ```

   You just need to modify in setTitle() body to better implement it:

   ```
   public void setTitle(String title) {
       getActivity().setTitle(title);
   }
   ```
2. For Menu options change, you are calling **invalidateOptionsMenu()** which will call **onPrepareOptionsMenu()** and your R.menu.menu will be set.

No modification is required in this case